# Extending parent state with extra views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

**Using**: AngularJS and UI-Router.

I am trying to create a page that has two views: `menu` and `main`. One is for a menu and the other is for whatever content there may be. However, I do not want to define both views in all states every time. The `menu` view will not change too often. So I created a parent 'root' state which contains only the `menu` view. The other states then derive from this and add appropriate views.

The code looks like this (in a file `app.js`):

```
angular
    .module('Admin', ["ui.router"])
    .config(["$stateProvider", function($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state('root', {
            abstract: true,
            views: {
                "menu": {
                    templateUrl: "../static/partials/menu.html",
                    controller: "MenuController"
                }
            }
        }).state('root.main', {
            url: "",
            parent: 'root',
            views: {
                "main": {
                    templateUrl: "../static/partials/landing.html",
                    controller: "MainController"
                }
            }
        }).state('root.login', {
            url: "/login",
            parent: 'root',
            views: {
                "main": {
                    templateUrl: "../static/partials/login.html",
                    controller: "LoginController"
                }
            }
        })
        ;
    }])
    .controller('MainController', ["$scope", "$http", mainController])
    .controller('MenuController', ["$scope", "$http", menuController])
    .controller('LoginController', ["$scope", "$http", loginController])
    ;
```

The result is that only the `menu` view is displayed. The `main` view is not displayed, unless I also add it to the `root` state. Anyone know what is wrong?

**EDIT**

The HTML that contains the views:

```
<div ng-app="Admin">
    <a ui-sref="root.main">Click me</a>
    <div class="ui menu" ui-view="menu"></div>
    <div class="ui segment">
        <div ui-view="main"></div>
    </div>
    <br>
</div>

<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/menu.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/main_controllers.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

**EDIT 2**

There is a similar question here: [UI-Router inheriting views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20439630/ui-router-inheriting-views), but this does not work for me...

**EDIT 3**

I managed to very simply reproduce this in plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/uYlFgsvq8hQHON8EESEx?p=preview

Comment: could you add your html please?

Comment: I added the HTML. If you think it is helpful that you see all of the HTML, with all the files I can do that. I am using Flask for the back-end, this is where the `url_for` functions come from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just had the same problem and found the solution using your plnkr. You need to add the '@' to the view name as shown below.

```
.state('root.main', {
    url: "",
    parent: 'root',
    views: {
        "main@": {
            templateUrl: "../static/partials/landing.html",
            controller: "MainController"
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your whole code is right only you need to call that route from UI by doing `ui-sref="root.main"` or `ui-sref=".main"`

**Markup**

```
<div ng-app="Admin">
    <a ui-sref="root.main">Click me</a>
    <div class="ui menu" ui-view="menu"></div>
    <div class="ui segment">
        <div ui-view="main"></div>
    </div>
    <br>
</div>
```

Comment: So, the main view becomes a nested view of menu? But this is conceptually wrong because it is not the case. Is there a way to add a root 'fake' view somehow but don't force a parent-child relationship between the menu and main views?

Comment: How do I call that route?

Comment: you need to add some anchor with `ui-sref="root.main"`  on html

Comment: I changed the code to reflect this. I added `<a ui-sref="root.main"></a>`, still doesn't work...

Comment: then you need to click on that link inorder to load state with template

Comment: I put the link in various places..still doesn't work when I click on it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76101/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-iulian).

Comment: I managed to quickly reproduce this in plnkr - see my edit or: http://plnkr.co/edit/uYlFgsvq8hQHON8EESEx?p=preview